# How do I print contents of at jobs?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, at

I have a Debian box with some jobs scheduled using `at`. I know I can list the jobs with their times using `atq`, but is there any way to print out their contents, apart from peeking into `/var/spool/cron/atjobs`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`at -c jobnumber` will list a single job. If you want to see all of them, you might create a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
MAXJOB=$(atq | head -n1 | awk '{ print $1; }')
for each in $(seq 1 $MAXJOB); do echo "JOB $each"; at -c $each; done
```

Probably there's a shorter way to do that, I just popped that out of my head :)

Comment: `at -c $(atq | cut -f 1)` or `for each in $(atq | cut -f 1)` will avoid "Cannot find jobid" errors. (Also, Bash has `for ((each=1; each<=MAXJOB; each++))` so no need for `seq`. If you're concerned with portability, then `#!/bin/sh`.)

Comment: don't forget good old `awk`, `atq | awk '{ system("at -c " $1) }'`

Answer (score 14):

Building upon previous responses, this lists each job's line from `atq` showing job number and scheduled time and then just the command to be run, sorted chronologically (rather than job number):

```
for j in $(atq | sort -k6,6 -k3,3M -k4,4 -k5,5 |cut -f 1); do atq |grep -P "^$j\t" ;at -c "$j" | tail -n 2; done
```

producing, e.g.

```
48  Fri Mar 10 15:13:00 2017 a root
/usr/local/bin/a-command

47  Fri Mar 10 15:14:00 2017 a root
/usr/local/bin/another-command
```

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler approach:

```
for j in $(atq | cut -f 1); do at -c "$j"; done
```

You could also look at each one in `less` in turn, which might be clearer:

```
for j in $(atq | cut -f 1); do at -c "$j" | less; done
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created command `atqc` for this ("atq with command"). A bash function. Run this on the bash command line (terminal command). Or put it in the `~/.bashrc` file to make it available for later:

```
atqc () { atq|perl -ne'($q,$j)=/((\d+).*)/;qx(at -c $j)=~/(marcinDEL\w+).\n(.*?)\n\1/s;print"$q $2"'; }
```

Test it:

```
atqc
```

That works for RHEL7 with `at -V` version 3.1.13.

Ubuntu 16.04 with `at -V` version 3.1.18 has a slightly different output format in `at -c N`, so on my Ubuntu server this works:

```
atqc(){ atq|perl -nE'($q,$j)=/((\d+).*)/;qx(at -c $j)=~/\n}\n(.*?)\s*$/s;say"$q: $1"';}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach, similar to the others in this thread but using awk more:

```
atq | awk '{ print "at -c " $1 }' | bash
```

To do a "dry run" and see what would be executed, simply remove the "| bash" part from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to have my at jobs listed by execution date plus their corresponding command line. Swap the `##` at line `get_at_line` if you prefer the output separated by blanks instead of columns.

```bash
me@PC3540:~$ which atl  
/home/me/bin/atl  
me@PC3540:~$ cat /home/me/bin/atl  
  
#!/bin/bash  
PFIX=A00000  
get_at_line () {  
for i in $(at -l | cut -f1 )  
do  
 ATLINE=$(at -l | grep ^$i)  
 ATSTATUS=$(echo $ATLINE | tr -s " " | cut -f7 -d" ")  
 ATTIME=$(echo $ATLINE | cut -f2- | cut -f1-6 -d" ")  
 ATISO=$(date -d "$ATTIME" +%Y-%m-%d' '%R)  
 ATCMD=$(at -c $i | sed -n -e '/}/,$p' | grep -v -e '}' )    
 HEX=$(printf '%x\n' $i)   
 VAL=$(printf "%X\n" $((0x$PFIX+0x$HEX)))  
 VAL=${VAL,,}  
 echo Job: $(printf "%02d\n" $i) $VAL At: $ATISO $ATSTATUS: $ATCMD  
done  
}  
if $(which at > /dev/null)  
then  
 if [ ! -z "$(at -l)" ]  
 then  
  get_at_line | sort -k5 -k6 | column -t -s" " -n  
  ##get_at_line | sort -k5 -k6  
 else  
  echo -e "\n.. no at jobs found for user $USER\n"  
 fi  
else   
 echo -e "\n.. service at not installed \n"  
fi
```